# Unknown column 'e.category_ids' in field list in product list

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, database, magento-community, magento2-migration-tool

We have an error in product list page, we trying to update product details page we getting the following error.
**exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.category_ids' in 'field list'' in**

After migrating database Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.0 we did reindex after that we got this above error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below query, but not able to find `category_ids` field in Magento 2 Database.

```
SELECT table_name,table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE column_name='category_ids'
```

In Magento 2: I'm only able to find `catalog_category_product` table for Category wise product relation table.

It has `entity_id`, `category_id`, `product_id`, `position` field only.

For index also we have `catalog_category_product_index`, `catalog_category_product_index_tmp`

For Migration please refer

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate-data.html

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento2-data-migration-tool/

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento-news/magento-2-data-migration-tool/

https://www.quora.com/When-migrating-from-Magento-1-to-Magento-2-how-does-one-migrate-a-specific-data-extension

https://magecomp.com/blog/migrating-magento-1-x-to-magento-2-0/

You can also some of the already available Migration Tool from Market Place.
Hope it helps